# How asp.net mvc knows this is Url or image path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have created a mvc application with controller name "Home" having action name "Index" and I have a folder in that application same as controller name "Home" having a image "abc.jpg" .

when i request a Url "hostname:111{/Home/Index}" it is navigating to index view .
when i request a url "hostname:111{/Home/abc.jpg}" it is navigating to image .

How it works when i request a image ?
is it working because of extension type of image ?

Answer (score 0):

first it checks if it can find your url in routing tables 'controller/action'. since abc.jpg is not a method thus path is not found in defined routes iis will look for folder 'home' and file 'abc.jpg'. it finds it and as it probably has mime-types defined for jpg extension it knows it should serve it as image.